# Get_terms returns error when more than one custom taxonomy exists

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, categories, custom-taxonomy

Hi people from StackOverflow!

I'm having a problem while using the get_terms function:

I have a website to design, with two levels of categories. For the first one I use the already existing Wordpress taxonomy "category", and for the second level, I created a custom taxonomy.

When the user loads a page, it gets all the custom post_type "content" and filters the results with the two levels of taxonomies set in the post, to show only the needed content.

I integrated all the content of my custom taxonomy's first occurrence, but when I added a new one, the previous ones were not working anymore:

get_terms(); returned the name of my new category even for the posts who were not tagged with it, in the page of the second taxonomy, and get_terms() returned an empty array in the first category's page.

When I deleted the second category, the problem disappeared and all the posts of the first category started working again.

The problem may come from the fact that instead of coding the custom taxonomy by myself, I used the "Simple Taxonomy" plugin, but no one seemed to really have problems with it on the internet, so I'm not sure if it comes from it.

I'll show you the part where I get the error:

```
<ul id="contentList">
    <?php query_posts('post_type=contenus&showposts=-1');
    while ( have_posts() )
        {
            the_post();
            $rubrique = get_terms('rubrique');
                if (ucwords($actual_rubrique) == $rubrique[0]->name){
                    echo '<a href="';
                    $url = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
                    echo $url[0];
                    echo '?tab=';
                    echo $post->ID;
                    echo '"><li>';
                    echo the_title();
                    echo '</li></a>';};?>
    <?php }; ?>
</ul>
```

When it works, get_terms() returns "Urbanisme" for the Urbanism category for example. (It's a french website)

EDIT:

I tried to change my way of thinking: Instead of doing all this on a cutsom post_type page, I moved it to page.php. I've still got the same problem:

When I just have one term, every page on the website is tagged with it, and when there are two, they all take the second one, even those who were checked to be in the first...

I really don't understand what's happening. Please help :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved:

I didn't understand how get_terms() worked. It just returned me an array of ALL the existing terms of my taxonomy.

To get the actual terms I used has_terms():

```
  if (has_term($actual_rubrique, 'rubrique', $post)){ do_stuff();};
```